# new svn server, same ip

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, uuid, wc

Here is my problem:

My server crashed last night! So i had to go out and buy some new stuff and i now have a new server. I have everything set back up and i am trying to set my svn server back up. I have it set back up. I have my files on another pc that i want to commit to the svn server to start my repository back up. How do i get those files into the repository again? The server has the same ip as it was before. I have tried a relocate and a switch, but i keep getting this error:

```
The repository at 'svn://<ip>/random' has uuid '<the uid>, but the WC has '<the uid>'.
```

The stuff in <> is left out, because it is not important information. The uid's are different. Can you please assist me asap! I need this up and running VERY VERY soon.

Thank you!

Comment: I know nothing about SVN servers, but that sounds like your user id is wrong. Did you set up the users on the server?

Comment: Nope, "uid" is the unique repository ID. How did you restore that repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a backup of your repository (from the server) you will loose history. You can create a new repository and import all your files from a working copy. (svn export from the old working copy to the new one and then adding and checking everything is i a way to go).

But then you have a new repository and can not do a relocate on the client. Instead you need to do a clean checkout in a new folder.

Answer (score 2):

There is the SVNADMIN command:

```
svnadmin setuuid <repos_path> <new_uuid>
```

You could use this to set the UUID of the new repository to the value of the old one.  That way, your working copy will not complain that the UUIDs do not match.