# SVN Switchover to a new server

Tags: svn, repository

We have been using the SVN from provider1. However, we now wish to switch over to a new URL with provider2.

In this connection I would like to checkout all the projects from provider1 and then relocate (commit) it to provider2.

Pl. elaborate the steps for it. As of now, when i try relocate in tortoise, I am getting a UUID mismatch error.

Thanks

Comment: use Git instead of SVN and simply copy the repos? To be serious: use `svnadmin dump` to get the history of each repo and then `svnadmin load` to relocate them on provider2. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.

Answer (score 3):

If svnadmin is not an option (no shell access to the server), there are tools such as rsvndump (http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/) to get the repository data.

Then import the data to the new location (either svnadmin, or talk to the service provider, they usually accept dumps to import, even if they don't like to export repo data).

After that, the uuid will match, so you can use svn switch to move over.

The uuid error is basically that you created a new repository, somehow got the data over, but each repository gets a unique ID (said uuid), which you didn't set appropriately (svnsync stores the origin's uuid, but as secondary information, not as 1:1 replication)

Comment: Oh, also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542560/new-svn-server-same-ip which describes how to change the UUID of your new repository after the fact: svnadmin setuuid <repos_path> <new_uuid>